# Spring frame work singleton bean concurrency management

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

Is there a concurrency management mechanism as @Lock(READ), and @Lock(WRITE) in java ee @Singleton, if there is not,how could I implement it using java se concurrency features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a concurrency management mechanism as @Lock(READ), and @Lock(WRITE) in java ee @Singleton?

I'm not sure what you mean by this.  `@Lock(READ)` or `@Lock(WRITE)` **is** a Java EE concurrency mechanism which can be used by `@Singleton`

> if there is not,how could I implement it using java se concurrency features.

You could use [`java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) which is one of the Java SE features.

For example:

```
final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

// equivalent to using @Lock(LockType.READ)
public void readData() {
  lock.readLock().lock();
  try {
    // read some data
  } finally {
    lock.readLock().unlock();
} 

// equivalent to using @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
public void writeData() {
  lock.writeLock().lock();
  try {
    // write some data
  } finally {
    lock.writeLock().unlock();
}
```